# In Foundry Scenarios, Is it possible to run functions across multiple scenarios?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios

I would like to run functions across a few of my Scenarios, but I'm not sure how to configure this. Is it possible to run functions across multiple Scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not currently possible to author code that operates across scenarios.

You can display values from multiple scenarios in the chart and table widgets using the comparison scenarios option.

You can also display values from function backed variables evaluated in different scenarios and even pass those results to a separate function to calculate differences, e.g., to calculate deltas between scenarios.